# How to route javascript files called inside another

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

How to route javascript files called inside another javascript in code igniter.

Comment: Can you show an example?

Comment: my folder structure is 
root/
      application
      system
      assets/js
I have no problem in reaching the js that are called from the view .
but I have problem in the includes from the inside of the js files .
I couldn't find any solution rather than changing the include to '../assets/js/file.js'

Comment: Did you found out how in the end? If not, show how you include the js file.